# WebDeploy application startup HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Getting this error after publishing with Web Deploy.  It doesn't say what json file it is trying to parse, so I was assuming appsettings.json but they appsettings files are all basically the auto generated settings from a new project.
Is there any way to get more detail about the cause?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '0': ''. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.Parse(Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at CFAR.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an empty appsettings.production.json file lingering on the server.  I didn't expect it b/c it had been removed from my project before the most recent web deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar problem
but it turned out that the json file was not well formated... missing a closing braket